# Como aguardar retorno para prosseguir com a execução do app? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, requisição

Tenho uma função `retornaDescricao()` que faz uma requisição http e edita o controller da variável com o valor recebido. Porém, o valor só é alterado quando aperto pela segunda vez no botão ElevatedButton() .

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AgregarUsuario extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AgregarUsuarioState createState() => _AgregarUsuarioState();
}

class _AgregarUsuarioState extends State<AgregarUsuario> {
  TextEditingController controlNombre = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controlTelefono = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controlEmail = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controlDescricao = new TextEditingController();

  Future retornaDescricao() async {
    var resposta;
    http.Response response;

    response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse("http://192.168.2.5/pruebas/obterDescricao.php"));
    resposta = json.decode(response.body);
    var lista = resposta;
    String descricao = lista[0]["nombre"];

    controlDescricao.text = descricao;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("AGREGAR USUARIO"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: controlNombre,
                decoration:
                    InputDecoration(labelText: "Código de barras - EAN"),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: controlTelefono,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Quantidade"),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0)),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //agregarUsuario();
                  setState(() {
                    retornaDescricao();

                    print("texto recebido: " + controlDescricao.text);
                  });

                  agregarUsuario();
                  //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
                },
                child: Text("Adicionar à impressão"),
              ),
              Container(
                  height: 35.0,
                  child: Text(
                    controlDescricao.text,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void agregarUsuario() {
    //var url = "http://192.168.0.11/pruebas/agregarUsuario.php";
    if (controlNombre.text == null || controlNombre.text == "") {
    } else {
      http.post(Uri.parse("http://192.168.2.5/pruebas/agregarUsuario.php"),
          body: {
            "nombre": controlNombre.text,
            "telefono": controlTelefono.text,
            "email": controlEmail.text,
          });
    }
  }
}
```

Retorno no console:

```
    Restarted application in 1.139ms.
    I/flutter ( 9135): texto recebido:
    2
    I/flutter ( 9135): texto recebido: 789000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Do jeito que você fez, existem duas saídas...

1º Forma (Não é a melhor)

Deixe o `onPressed` do *ElevatedButton* async e aguarde o retorno do *Future*, mesmo sendo void.

```
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              //agregarUsuario();
              setState(() {
                await retornaDescricao();

                print("texto recebido: " + controlDescricao.text);
              });

              agregarUsuario();
              //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
            },
            child: Text("Adicionar à impressão"),
          ),
```

---

2º Forma (Que é melhor em questão de organização)

Mova o `setState` para dentro da função `retornaDescricao()`.

```
         ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              //agregarUsuario();
              retornaDescricao();
              agregarUsuario();
              //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
            },
            child: Text("Adicionar à impressão"),
          ),
```

[...]

```
  Future retornaDescricao() async {
    var resposta;
    http.Response response;

    response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse("http://192.168.2.5/pruebas/obterDescricao.php"));
    resposta = json.decode(response.body);
    var lista = resposta;
    String descricao = lista[0]["nombre"];

    setState(() {
      controlDescricao.text = descricao;
      print("texto recebido: " + controlDescricao.text);
    }
  }
```

*Obs.: Caso for querer usar o `controlDescricao` dentro da função `agregarUsuario()`, você vai ter que deixar o click do botão async e usar o `await` na chamada do método `retornaDescricao()`.*

### Explicação

A forma como você fez, não aguarda o término da chamada do método `retornaDescricao()`, sendo assim ele chama o método e logo em seguida já imprime o valor antigo da variável.

Digo que a 1ª forma não é a melhor, pois dentro de um `setState` não é aconselhado fazer muitas operações, então use-o apenas onde realmente for setar um valor final (De preferência já computado) que precisa ser atualizado em tela.

Se quiser dar uma olhada, escrevi um artigo sobre funções assínconas...

[Flutter Descomplica - Funções Assíncronas](https://medium.com/@matheusrmribeiro/flutter-descomplica-funcoes-assincronas-ab5380d276dc)

Answer (score 0):

Tu podes usar os métodos do Future. `then` será invocado quando o Future for resolvido.  É bom usar o `catchError` também para tratar possíveis erros da requisição.

```dart
     ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              retornaDescricao()
               .then((_)=>{
                   setState(() {});
                   print("texto recebido: " + controlDescricao.text);
                   agregarUsuario();
                  //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
               })
               .catchError((error) => print("Ops... algo deu errado"));
            },
            child: Text("Adicionar à impressão"),
          ),
```

Referência: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-async/Future-class.html